# carousel javascript without jquery inside the button

Tags: javascript, carousel

I am trying to use only JavaScript (without jQuery and Bootstrap) inside the button.

How to create a carousel-like effect by clicking on the rectangular buttons with pure JS and CSS?

I am using following carousel code:

```css
.carousel-inner {
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      First
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      Second
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      Third
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

It is a screenshot of what I want:
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. "Inside the button" what does that mean?

Comment: @mplungjan : i attached one image in content.Please check

Comment: The image does not explain what you mean by `how to use carousel inside the button without query and boot strap.`

Comment: I've trouble to understand your question; are you meaning how to create a carousel-like effect by clicking on the rectangular buttons with pure JS and CSS?

Comment: @MaximeLaunois:yes

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about HTMLElements.  You can explore them in your web inspector console by typing `document.body` and then digging into the object.  They have lots of functionality, you don't need to know it all, but if you're going with [vanilla js](http://vanilla-js.com/), good on you!

The big things you need to know are `childNodes`, eventListeners, and `offsetLeft`.

Something along these lines (untested) should get you most of the way there.

```
const byId = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
const buttonContainer = byId("ButtonContainer");
const imageContainer = byId("ImageContainer");

let lastSelectedButton;

Array.from(buttonContainer.childNodes).forEach((child, childIndex) => {
  child.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (lastSelectedButton) {
       lastSelectedButton.classList.remove("selected");
    }

    const scrollToMe = imageContainer.childNodes[childIndex];
    imageContainer.scrollX = scrollToMe.offsetLeft;

    child.classList.add("selected");
    lastSelectedButton = child;
  });
});
```

And if you really want to spice it up, add some [Scroll Snapping](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/).

And if you're not trying to do a scrolly version at all and just switch out, use `child.remove()` and `element.appendChild(child)`.